# Kubernetes how node with mulitple pods is managed

Tags: kubernetes, operating-system

I am currently into k8s and having lots of question.

I know that a kube-scheduler detects and assigns newly created pods to a node.

However, I am wondering how scheduling works with pods that are already assigned to a node.

What if there is are 3 pods with different priorities and they do not terminate and run in a loop until a node fails.

Lets say the node is a physical machine with linux as OS and has 4 cpu.

Assuming the situation like above I have two questions.

First, does the node run on one cpu or can it be run in multiple cpus like threads are treated?

Second,if the pods are not running parrel in different cpu. How or what manages which pod to run on a node? Does the kube-sched do it or is there something schedules the pods so that they can run concurrently?

Thank you all for your kindness reading my question.

Looked through kubernetes.io
Youtube of cncf, azure, ibm but failed to find an answer

Comment: A Pod runs a container fundamentally runs a process, and "which core is my process assigned to" or "what happens if there are more processes than cores" is generally managed by the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a story of how threading and throttling works on medium.com if you wanna read in [depth](https://medium.com/binome/going-down-the-rabbit-hole-of-threads-77a41c3eb888).

But to answer your questions. I am going to assume the pods are 3 webservers waiting for connections and just sitting there indefinitely.

1. The node is the actual machine, so it uses all all cpus available to it, the containers on the other hand are scheduled INTO the node and they can be scheduled on the CPU for a limited amount of time depending on your resources block configuration.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: images.my-company.example/app:v4
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

That block will define how much CPU and how much memory that container will get assigned, but it can only be as big as the amount the node has. In your example if you have a node with 4 cpus, and you REQUEST a node with :

```
spec.containers[].resources.requests.cpu = 4
```

Then one pod will only be able to fit on one node and be scheduled on that one node.

2. Kube scheduler is the Kubernetes component in charge of placing pods in nodes. It uses a component called `kubelet` which is an agent that runs on every node that reports back to the api-server (kube-scheduler queries this api server for node status) and tries to fit containers on nodes.
3. In terms of threads I wrote another post detailing that process, you can read it [here](https://medium.com/binome/the-kernel-on-containers-fac07ff0712c).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. It was very helpful. Now I am curious about after when resources such as cpu time slice ,cores are allocated to pods. Does the kernel context switch between the pods or is it the kubernetes work to context switch btw pods according to amount of resource allocated to the pods? Also, if the kernel does the work how does it know the allocated amount of time slices to each pod? Thank you :D

Comment: The component how does the context switch between containers is the Kernel in the OS, Kubernetes is a platform, so it's responsabilities lie in scheduling containers to nodes and networking broadly speaking, the actual CPU allocation happens at the operating system level. With regards to your other question, there is an algorithim called CFS, it stands for "Completely Fair Scheduler and you can google that to see how time slices are assigned.